# Resend autocomplete init function to google maps api

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I have a function called "autocompleteAddress" where is is initializing the auto complete on a certain input. This function looks like this as per do

```
function initAutocomplete() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
  // location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
      {types: ['geocode']});

  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
  // fields in the form.
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}
```

Now at the bottom I have the normal script where I send the function name to google api, like following

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
        async defer></script>
```

Now I am doing some modifications to the UI, and after those modifications the auto complete doesn't work any more, reason being that specific input is destroyed and a new one is created.

Now my question is is there a way I can tell Google that I have updated my input to another one. Like resending the function sort of speak.

Comment: Why can't you call the function (`initAutocomplete`) again after making the modifications to the UI?  Doesn't look like it has any other side effects (and the API will already be loaded).

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have figured it out  I just need to call the constructor again like so

```
google_autocomplete.autocomplete.constructor(document.getElementById('element'))
```